# Moving objects from one GCS bucket to another Bucket using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'd like to use `Terraform` to move multiple `GCS bucket objects` from one `bucket` to another `bucket` to a different location.

I read through `Terraform` documentation but I couldn't find anything substantial.

Answer (score 3):

Terraform for Cloud Storage provider only handles creation of object. What you can do as a workaround is to use [Terraform with Storage Transfer Service](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/storage_transfer_job.html) which schedules a job that transfers multiple objects to a GCS bucket which either came from AWS S3 or another GCS.

Since this is a GCS to GCS transfer, you can take note of:

1. Under `transfer spec` block, only specify the `gcs_data_source` to indicate that it is a GCS to GCS transfer.
2. The `schedule` block specifies the time when the transfer will start. If you intend to execute it just once, you can specify the `schedule_end_date` immediately.

The Storage Transfer Service feature also offers guide through the Google Cloud Console should you want to try it out:
https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-console#configure

Comment: Thanks. I understand that I can specify the source via `gcs_data_source`. How do I specify the destination ?

Comment: You specify it using `gcs_data_sink`. Also, take note that the data sink for storage transfer is always a Cloud Storage bucket.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!